# unable to update a value inside an entity to null using PUT request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a method for updating customer Entity  using PUT request in my Java Spring boot project. There is a field notificationId inside customer entity. Below is a statement from this method.

```
customerEntity.setNotificationId(customerDto.getNotificationId() == null ? customerEntity.getNotificationId() : customerDto.getNotificationId());
```

This statement works as expected but if the customer once updates notificationId to eg: `12345` and then again wants to update to `null`, he is not able to update to `null`. I tried some changes in the logic, but no use. Kindly suggest changes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a standard problem when mapping JSON to Java DTOs. JSON knows the difference between a key that's just not there (`{}`), and `{"key"=null}` property. In Java, both those versions will map to `key = null`. Your PUT endpoint ignores `null` values, so that you can PUT partial updates and leave other fields untouched. That's what the code you posted is doing:

```
customerEntity.setNotificationId(customerDto.getNotificationId() == null ? customerEntity.getNotificationId() : customerDto.getNotificationId());
```

If the posted value is `null`, it uses the value from the (existing) entity instead. A more readable variant would be:

```
if (customerDto.getNotificationId() != null) {
  customerEntity.setNotificationId(customerDto.getNotificationId());
}
```

How you solve this problem is up to you. There are several options, including but not limited to:

- Create a PATCH endpoint in addition to the PUT endpoint, which has different semantics regarding how `null` values are handled
- Parse the incoming JSON in a different way, so that you know whether the client specificied an explicit `null` or just omitted the property.

Comment: thanks Jorn. could you share sample code to parse incoming JSON in a different way?

Comment: That's a bit much for one comment, but one option would be to parse to a `Map`. Then, you can distinguish between `containsKey=false` and `get(key)=null`. Of course, now you have lost type safety and Spring features like validation.